# How to keep value of cshtml view object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, razor, datepicker

Inside the cshtml view I have a dropdown list with 2 possible options. If selection returns "True", a container with 2 datepickers becomes visible, so user can select a daterange. Whenever I switch dropdown option, both datepickers are assigned with respective values.

```
$("#ExpirationChoice").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();  //picks up either True or False

    if (val) {
        if (val === "True") {
            $("#expirationDates").show();    //show container with datepickers
            $("#BeginDate").val(getFormattedDate(today()));
            $("#EndDate").val(getFormattedDate(today().addMonths(6)));
        }
        else {
            $("#expirationDates").hide();
            $("#BeginDate").val("");
            $("#EndDate").val(getFormattedDate(today()));
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please select an option of past or future expiration report.");
    }
});
```

Let's assume I picked True from dropdown, selected a 1 month range between 12/23/16 and 01/23/17, clicked the button to generate a table.

Then, I switched dropdown option to False, which caused to hide container and reassign date values to `empty` and `today` in datepickers (hidden, thus, can't be controlled by user).

Now, when I switch back to True again, my selections are gone, it again assigns it to a 6-month range (I understand why it does it, I will explain my attempts later).

My question is: **How to keep my latest selections from True option whenever I switch?**

## A challenge through my attempts

I understand exactly why it was behaving the following way. My way of thinking is to store selections of datepickers from True option into variables. However, here is a challenge that I am suddenly running into:

```
if (val === "True") {
   $("#expirationDates").show();

   $("#BeginDate").val(getFormattedDate(today()));
   $("#EndDate").val(getFormattedDate(today().addMonths(6)));

   var start = $("#BeginDate").val();
   var end = $("#EndDate").val();
}
```

I need to initially assign dates to be a 6-month daterange. So far variables store dates properly. However, whenever I switch, date values will be reassigned back to 6 month range, and it turns into an infinite loop.

**Pretty much, I would appreciate any direction in terms of the better approach for such problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main challenge of my case was getting an updated value from datepickers. After doing some additional research, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236703/val-not-getting-updated-value-from-input) as a hint to resolve my issue. Therefore, instead of getting latest values from .change(), I stored necessary values on .click()

```
$("#btnExpiringUnitsTable").click(function () {
    var e = document.getElementById("ExpirationChoice");
    var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //code
    if (selectedOption === "True") {    //store latest datepicker values in variables from "True" selection
        start = $("#BeginDate").val();
        end = $("#EndDate").val();
    }
    //code
});
```

As for my initial .change(function), it narrowed it down to the following:

```
$("#ExpirationChoice").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();


    if (val) {
        if (val === "True") {
            $("#expirationDates").show();
            $("#BeginDate").val(start);
            $("#EndDate").val(end);
        }
        else {
            $("#expirationDates").hide();
            $("#BeginDate").val("");
            $("#EndDate").val(getFormattedDate(today()));
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please select an option of past or future expiration report.");
    }
});
```

From what I see, I will not be able to pick up updated values from .change(), I would have to go with .click().

Answer (score 0):

use a flag var

```
var flag = false; //global variable
var start;//global variable
var end;//global variable
if (val === "True") {
   $("#expirationDates").show();

   if(flag == false){
       $("#BeginDate").val(getFormattedDate(today()));
       $("#EndDate").val(getFormattedDate(today().addMonths(6)));
   }
   else {
       $("#BeginDate").val(start);
       $("#EndDate").val(end);
   }
   start = $("#BeginDate").val();
   end = $("#EndDate").val();
   flag = true;
}
```

Comment: Nope. On the false flag, datepickers are assigned the 6-month range, and these values are assigned to start and end at the bottom. Now that the flag is set to true, datepickers are assigned to start and end values, which are 6-month range values.